How to bypass many Update() in Pipeline codes?
Good people. I have implemented a pipeline code in which the input (SetInputConnection()) for a connection is the output port of another filter, which is obtained with GetOutputPort().
Here, I have to call Update() before if() conditions to get the up-to-date data, and with this, the code works fine. Now, I am wondering if it is possible to keep 1 Update() call in the VTK pipeline at the very end and remove the first and second Update(). The question is ***

how to satisfy the if condition

*** then.
if ( surfaceFilter->GetOutput()->GetNumberOfPoints() > 0 ) 
{
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkCleanPolyData> clean = vtkSmartPointer<vtkCleanPolyData>::New();
    clean->SetInputConnection( surfaceFilter->GetOutputPort() );
    clean->Update(); //Bring this outputs up-to-date.

    if ( clean->GetOutput()->GetNumberOfPoints() >= 3 ) //*If we have the previous line update() then clean->GetOutput()->GetNumberOfPoints() has some values otherwise 0
    {
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkLoopSubdivisionFilter> subdivision = vtkSmartPointer<vtkLoopSubdivisionFilter>::New();
        subdivision->SetInputConnection(clean->GetOutputPort() );
        subdivision->Update();

        if ( subdivision->GetOutput()->GetNumberOfPoints() > 0 ) //If we have the previous line update then subdivision->GetOutput()->GetNumberOfPoints() has some values otherwise 0
        {
            ....


            vtkSmartPointer<vtkSmoothPolyDataFilter> smooth = vtkSmartPointer<vtkSmoothPolyDataFilter>::New(); 
            smooth->SetInputConnection(subdivision->GetOutputPort());
            smooth->Update();//**Is it possible to keep this final Update() and remove previous two Update() and wondering how those two if() will satisfy?**
        }
    }
}


Why does no one want answers from evil people? I feel so left out!
